# Symfony: run console command with different environment during request

Tags: symfony, .env

I'm running one symfony code base with three different environments, each with their own database. User logins aren't shared between the two, but administrators of one environment should be able to log in to the other, without a password.

For this, I've created a command to generate a one-time valid login link.

```
#[AsCommand(
    name: 'app:generate:login',
    description: 'Generates a login link for the given user',
)]
class GenerateLoginCommand extends Command
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly UserRepository $userRepository,
        #[Autowire(service: 'security.authenticator.login_link_handler.main')] private readonly LoginLinkHandlerInterface $linkHandler,
    )
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure(): void
    {
        $this
            ->addArgument('user', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Username of the user to generate the login for')
            ->addArgument('expires', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Expiry time in seconds, default 10')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
        $username = $input->getArgument('user');
        $expires = $input->getArgument('expires') ?? 10;

        $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['username' => $username]);
        $details = $this->linkHandler->createLoginLink($user, null, intval($expires));

        $io->writeln($details->getUrl());

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

This works well enough, if I run it as a console command. If I however run this in http request, the behaviour is not as expected:

```
#[Route(path: '/login_link', name: 'app_login_link')]
public function generateLoginLink(Request $request, KernelInterface $kernel, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');

    $env = $request->query->get('env', $kernel->getEnvironment());
    $username = $request->query->get('user', 'admin');

    $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(['username' => $username]);
    if (!$user) {
        $this->addFlash('warning', "Target user $username doesn't exist");
        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }
    foreach ($user->getRoles() as $role) {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted($role);
    }

    $kernel = new Kernel($env, $kernel->isDebug());
    $kernel->boot();
    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);
    $input = new ArrayInput([
        'command' => 'app:generate:login',
        'user' => $username,
        'expires' => 10
    ]);
    $output = new BufferedOutput();
    $application->run($input, $output);

    $content = $output->fetch();
    $urlpos = strpos($content, 'https://');
    $url = substr($content, is_bool($urlpos) ? 0 : $urlpos);
    $nlpos = strpos($url, "\n");
    $url = substr($url, 0, $nlpos ?: null);

    return $this->redirect($url);
}
```

For some reason or another, despite initializing a kernel with environment "two", the command is initialized and run with environment "one", which handled the http request. Therefore, the link generated is one.domain.local (set default_uri in routing options) instead of two.domain.local.
If I run the command with `php bin/console app:generate:login --env=two` everything works as expected, however.

So my question, how do I "switch" the environment during a request, or at least run a console command in a different environment?

Comment: If you want to run a command through a controller, you should restructure your application. Both a command class and a controller class should not contain that much logic. Put that into seperate services instead, and call these services from your controller and your command with the neccessary arguments

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, but that is unfortunately completely irrelevant to the question I've asked.

Not to mention, neither is calling a command from a controller a terrible idea in this case, nor is 35 lines of code for the entire command "too much". https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html

The reason I chose to implement it in a command (containing 3 whole lines of actual logic!) is because in order to switch the environment, the only way I could find was to instanciate a new Kernel and run an Application through that.

Comment: Points for a novel approach.  I am wondering about your `security.authenticator.login_link_handler.main` service.  Did you implement your own LoginLinkHandler?  The default one (`FirewallAwareLoginLinkHandler) relies on having a current request object so I don't see how it would work standalone.  Can you update your question with the code for your custom LoginLinkHandler?  Or if it an out of the box class then please indicate which class it being used.  Have you tried just using the process command and setting the env command argument?

Comment: @Cerad security.authenticator.login_link_handler.<FIREWALL> refers to Symfonys default LoginLinkHandler for a specific Firewall. The FirewallAwareLoginLinkHandler is only used if you do not specify the firewall name when autowiring.

Yes, I've tried using the Process component and that gives the expected result. But the recommended way to call commands is instantiating a new Application with a new Kernel, so I'm confused as to why that wouldn't work and just result in the current environment being used anyhow.

Comment: It is a bit puzzling.  I copied/pasted your GenerateLoginCommand and, as expected, got a `service not found` for the link handler.  I'm just using an out of the box 6.2 app after running `make:user` and `make:auth`.  Are you specifying the handler in security.yaml?  I'm interested in tracking down why your approach is not working but I can't get past the handler issue.  Perhaps you could post the results of `bin/console debug:container security.authenticator.login_link_handler.main`?

Comment: @Cerad sorry, I should've mentioned that you must enable login_link for the firewall in question. You can read more about it here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/login_link.html

Output:
https://pastebin.com/9uXYe6f3

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the environment variables are tied to the php process. The two ways to achieve this are to manually parse the configuration of the other environment and send a Message to a queue, or to spawn a new process to run the console command.

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process(['php', 'bin/console', 'your:command', '--env=other_env']);
$process->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was posting my `sort of` answer when I saw the OP's answer.  Not entirely sure about this `tied to process thing`.

I changed the default uri by:

```
# config/routing.yaml

# This is the only change for env=two
when@two:
    framework:
        router:
            strict_requirements: null
            default_uri: /two.domain.local`
```

Verified that running generate login worked as expected from the command line which, incidently, creates the var/cache/two directory with it's own container.

I then added a controller action:

```
    #[Route('/login_link', name: 'app_login_link')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $env = 'two';
        $kernel = new Kernel($env, true);
        $kernel->boot();
        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);
        $input = new ArrayInput([
            'command' => 'app:generate:login',
            'user' => 'ahundiak',
            'expires' => 10
        ]);
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);

        $content = $output->fetch();
        dd($content);
```

And got: `"http://localhost/two.domain.local/login_check?user=ahundiak&expires=...`

I only tried this locally using the Symfony development server but it all seemed to work.

If this does not seem to match your results then consider creating a new project and just adding the absolute minimum to recreate the issue and checking it into a repo.

Mind you I am not endorsing this approach to running a command but it really should work.

Comment: Define the default_uri in a .env.<env> file and you'll see that it doesn't update. But even in your case, try to actually use the link it generated. It will log you into the environment that you're currently already in, anyway.

I've confirmed it on the Symfony slack, unfortunately I haven't been given a suggestion on how to solve this problem (log user into a different environment automatically) in a better fashion.

Edit: 
stof
  18 hours ago
environment variables are tied to a PHP process, not to a kernel